# How can i get the deleted custom domain?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I accidentally deleted the custom domain that was assigned to my site. How do I undo this operation?Is there anyway to get my custom domain back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot undo it. You will have to perform the domain validation again and add it to the site.

Comment: hmm.. Thank you, I will validate the domain and add it.